# CSS Header and Page images background

Tags: html, css, background-image

Well I'm new at CSS and HTML. What I'm trying to achive it's to have a Header Background Image and a page background image, this page background should repeat with the content.

**Here you have the CSS style sheet...**

```
body,td,th {
    color: #18130E;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height:15px;
}
body {
    background: white url("images/test_bg4.jpg");
    background-color: #F6F3E0;
    margin:0px;
}
.header {
    height:164px;
    width:1032px;
    padding-top:66px;
    margin-top: 1cm;
    position:relative;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-516px;
    background-image: url("images/header_back.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:top center;
}

    .page {
        height:164px;
        width:1032px;
        padding-top:66px;
        margin-top: 1cm;
        position:relative;
        left:50%;
        margin-left:-516px;
        background-image:url("images/bb2.png");
        background-repeat:repeat-y;

    }
```

**And my HTML ...**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Lore Ipsum</title>
</head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<body>

<div class="header">

</div>

<div class="page">

<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam ut massa fringilla, malesuada neque ac, dapibus nunc. Vivamus ac rhoncus magna, vitae congue massa. Proin nec urna sed dolor mollis condimentum ut a ipsum. Proin dignissim malesuada nulla volutpat pellentesque. Donec maximus, tellus auctor vehicula pretium, elit augue consequat velit, eget tempus felis dolor eget justo. Sed iaculis eros quam, molestie venenatis odio varius sed. Fusce nibh tortor, vehicula vitae nunc at, lacinia auctor massa. Etiam egestas pulvinar rutrum. Maecenas auctor felis ut tempor dignissim. Donec vitae gravida libero. Aliquam convallis dignissim gravida. Duis fringilla, erat nec egestas tristique, lacus ex ultricies nunc, in ultricies lectus neque quis neque. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi egestas cursus ornare. Morbi accumsan auctor ex non lacinia. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
</p>
<p>
Cras sed imperdiet eros. In ac tincidunt mi. Aliquam consectetur ultricies turpis, at rhoncus ante accumsan a. Pellentesque ex turpis, venenatis a egestas eget, condimentum id velit. Sed molestie justo sed tortor tempor, vel scelerisque mauris pharetra. Sed eget ipsum ultrices, pretium purus id, ornare quam. Ut viverra orci pellentesque, dictum nulla in, laoreet eros. Aenean quis placerat libero. Nunc eu metus eu sem suscipit eleifend. Cras molestie mauris quis bibendum congue. Morbi ac risus quis metus vulputate lacinia. Pellentesque efficitur arcu quis est feugiat, ut elementum augue fringilla.
</p>
<p>
Duis consequat non nisi eget dapibus. Proin ultrices vel risus sit amet sagittis. Integer vulputate fermentum purus vitae feugiat. Donec semper, est eget suscipit pretium, est felis ultrices nulla, pulvinar mollis turpis arcu ac diam. Maecenas et lobortis magna. Aliquam mattis purus quis eros dapibus, in dignissim mi finibus. Etiam suscipit urna vitae tempus molestie. Duis eleifend ligula orci, et eleifend mauris imperdiet et. Nunc ac risus enim. Quisque sodales bibendum bibendum. Maecenas velit sem, auctor id est quis, tincidunt venenatis nibh. Sed sollicitudin vitae ligula non consectetur.
</p>
<p>
In eros libero, aliquet in enim eu, pellentesque condimentum nulla. Donec ullamcorper lobortis risus, vitae auctor mauris rutrum in. Praesent accumsan vitae magna id imperdiet. Nunc auctor ante non turpis mattis ultricies. Suspendisse viverra nibh id enim cursus commodo. Donec blandit, lectus sed scelerisque eleifend, nisi sem fringilla lacus, scelerisque auctor ex nisl iaculis nisl. Morbi velit sapien, elementum vitae vehicula vestibulum, lobortis eu lorem. Sed cursus sed urna id mattis. Nulla consectetur facilisis auctor. Nullam hendrerit eget sem vitae suscipit.
</p>
<p>
Aenean vel magna luctus, auctor urna et, vulputate lacus. Proin enim libero, dignissim sed faucibus id, tincidunt convallis arcu. Phasellus in finibus erat, sit amet luctus mi. Etiam at pellentesque magna, vel euismod felis. Phasellus consectetur augue elit, ac convallis magna bibendum ut. Cras et elit nulla. Etiam hendrerit auctor tortor, non consectetur justo viverra eu. Nullam scelerisque porttitor felis eget accumsan. Sed nec mauris libero. Pellentesque rhoncus leo in metus lacinia, a elementum justo interdum.
</p>


</div>

</body>

</html>
```

**But the problem is that what is happening is this ...**
[image: http://i.imgur.com/AAgo9mv.jpg]

The two images are suppose to be one under the oder, like one page.

Comment: Do you have a live link? I just tried copying and pasting your above code and it seems to work fine for me.

Comment: You really shouldn't be using relative positioning to layout your elements like that. [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: Sorry I'm working in local. 
I'll take a look thanks @Paulie_D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok there are a few things going on here that make this website work in a funky way, I will give you some suggestions:

1. Give the widths of your header and page classes a percentage (example: 80%).
2. Remove the left: 50% as it breaks the flow of the page.
3. Remove the margin-left: -516px as it also has the negative effect that left: 50% does. You can achieve shifting your elements to the right by giving a margin-left, but I believe you are using it improperly by making it center your elements on the page, in order to solve this you should see #4.
4. Give margin: 0 auto to your page and header classes in order to center them in the page.
5. Remove position: relative from your page and header classes, unless you have other elements which will have different positioning (like absolute/fixed).
6. Give a max-width to your header and page elements, the value is up to your consideration. This will ensure that the width of your elements is not only what you want it to be, but it will also be fluid on different browser widths.
7. Refer to any documentation regarding 'mobile first CSS' which will give you a HUGE boost in knowledge for the future, even if you only desire to make very simple websites it goes without saying this knowledge goes a long way.

Once you have done this, let me know if it helped and update your code if you have more questions that we can help out with.

Comment: I do everything you said and it worked, the only issue is that if the max-width is greater than the width of the background image, the page background is still moving to the left. Do you know the reason of this?

Comment: That is expected because the container will expand more than the full width of the image. In that case give background-size: cover to your background image, it will force it to extend to the full width of its containing element. It may also help to apply 'center' to property as well to keep your background image centered. If I interpret you accurately then that is the approach you need to try, let me know if that's not working for you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is waht you're expecting.

Try:

```
<div class="header common">
</div>
<div class="page common">
</div>
```

css:

```
.header {
    background-image: url("images/header_back.png");
}
.common{
    height:164px;
    width:1032px;
    padding-top:66px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
}
.page {
    background-image:url("images/bb2.png");
}
```

[Here's a Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ct0k5b1y/1/)